# Any gotchas with ViewPager?

Tags: android

I am converting my app with multiple list views into a ViewPager app.  Need to support 2.1+ so I am using the compatibility library.  Are there any gotchas related to the use of ViewPager? Memory issues or crashes that I need to be wary of?  My app is very heavily downloaded, 1M+, so I don't want to get biten if there is some known issues out there.  I saw there are some options to keep the pages in memory, are there any dangers with this as far as memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

Just imagine (or if you prefer, simulate) all of your app's tabs/lists running simultaneously, because that's what `ViewPager` does. They're all kept in memory and running. If it gets too RAM-heavy, consider unloading a fragment far away from the user's current position, and reloading it when the user gets close again.